# Store value of span or textarea in angularjs view

Tags: html, asp.net, angularjs

I have a call to a controller in my ASP.NET WebForms page:

input type="button" data-ng-click="addReply(post.PostId, LoggedInDisplayName, post.NewReply)" value="Submit" id="createReply" class="btn btn-default pull-right"

LoggedInDisplayName is a variable I need to pass to the addReply method, which does a RESTful API HTTP call in the service.

Unfortunately LoggedInDisplayName is a field that can only be sourced by ASP, as this is the login name of the current user, and I'm using Microsoft's built-in membership profile routines.

I can place the login name into a hidden span or textarea element using this logic in my code-behind C# file:

```
        if (Membership.GetUser() != null)
        {
            loggedInDisplayName.InnerText = Membership.GetUser().ToString();
        }
```

where loggedInDisplayName is the ID of the span or textarea.

But, how can I get the contents of the span or textarea into the LoggedInDisplayName field?  I tried using ng-model, but this doesn't work - the span/textarea is reverted to a blank field.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

just put in your submit button, ng-init="loggedInDisplayName = (asp variable)". This will initialize the variable to your asp variable.

Comment: My asp variable isn't actually available to the HTML  page.  All I can do is inject the variable into a SPAN  and then use ng-init to access the DOM and then populate the variable. Can ng-init access the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I loaded the asp variable into the DOM as follows

span style="visibility:hidden" id="loggedInDisplayName" ><%: LoggedInDisplayName() %>

And in the .cs code behind file:

```
    public string LoggedInDisplayName()
    {

        string loggedInDisplayName = "";

        // set the login name for use in creating new posts and replies
        if (Membership.GetUser() != null)
        {
            loggedInDisplayName = Membership.GetUser().ToString();
        }

        return loggedInDisplayName;

    }
```

Then a controller to create the variable in the scope

```
// The Global Variable defined outside angular
var loggedInDisplayName = $('#loggedInDisplayName').text();

//Define Controller
gwApp.controller('LoginName', ['$scope', '$window',
function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.LoggedInDisplayName = $window.loggedInDisplayName;
}
]);
```

I wrapped my existing controller in the new controller:

div id="loginName" data-ng-controller="LoginName">

... existing code ...

/div>

Then my Submit button:

input type="button" data-ng-click="addReply(post.PostId, LoggedInDisplayName, post.NewReply)" value="Submit" id="createReply{{ post.PostId }}" class="btn btn-default pull-right" />